# perlpod: missing text issue

Tags: perl, perl-pod

I'm having a issue where pod2usage is missing text, and I have tried to fix it by:

1. **converting newlines**
2. **rewriting it**
3. **checking it with podchecker**

but none of these things help to resolve or hint to my problem

**output of podchecker:**

```
YaTC.pod pod syntax OK.
```

**Full pod:**

http://pastebin.com/igH8SamN

**Pod2text output:**

*snip*

```
Bool: Use special characters

    If Nth = 0, this is the left arrow
Data: ISO Language Code:



    * Missing data *


    <http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_language_codes.asp?output=print>
    <http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes>
Data: Main size:

* Missing data *


    Maximum size limit, where Nth = 0 if X axis
Data: Minimum size:
```

*snip*

**Info:**

**My OS is** *OpenSuSE 11.4 Linux 2.6.37.6-0.7-default i686 i686 i386, GNU/Linux*

**My editor is** *SciTE Version 1.77*

**Also** *The POD is embedded in Perl code and pod2text is called thru the following code:*

```
    if ( !$conf{'Bool_Use_plain_text_for_help'} ) {
    my $help = $helpframe->PodText(
        -scrollbars => '',
        -file       => $0,
        -wrap       => 'word',
        -background => 'white',
        -width      => 150,
        -height     => 500
    )->pack( -side => 'top', -fill => 'both', -expand => 1 );
}
else {
    my $help = $helpframe->Text(
        -wrap       => 'word',
        -background => 'white',
        -width      => 150,
        -height     => 500
    )->pack( -side => 'top', -fill => 'both', -expand => 1 );

    $help->insert( 'end', qx{pod2text '$0'} );
}
```

**Pod2text version:** *unknown ( not in `man`, `info`, `help` or `pod2text --help` )*

**Terminal info:**

```
TERM=xterm
COLORTERM=1
```

**Edit:** *This bug seems to stem from Tk::Text, I tried pod2html in the console, and it seems ok, but in Tk it is missing text*

Comment: Can you put your POD somewhere, formatted exactly the way you want, and let us download it? The problem is that spaces are important to a POD document, so trying to cut it out of your post might introduce stuff that can cause side effects. If you have [Dropbox](http://dropbox.com), you can put your POD in the Public folder and then send us the link.

Comment: @DavidW. Yes look at my post.

Comment: Do the normal debugging stuff. Start removing parts of the Pod until the problem no longer appears. After that, add stuff until it reappears. You should then know what part of the Pod is causing the problem. From the warnings, it looks like a malformed L<>.

Comment: Is all of that indentation intentional? POD considers indented blocks of text to be "verbatim blocks" (i.e. for code) and not ordinary running text.

Comment: @hobbs no my text editor indents things when I don't want to.

Comment: @brian I will try what you said.

Comment: @brian +1 for giving good debug technique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just downloaded the pod you posted, and everything seems to work fine. I used both the `perldoc` and the `pod2text` command on my Mac and on a Windows XP box. Both produced the correct POD without any errors.

The only issue I had with your POD is that it was marked as being in Unix format, but it had CRLF on the end of each line. I used VIM to remove the "CR" character (it shows up as ^M). However, that didn't affect the POD itself.

I also did a `pod2text pod3.txt > pod_text.txt` and examined the resulting text file. Again, everything looks good.

Are you still having a problem? It doesn't appear to be a problem with the POD itself, and both `perldoc` and `pod2text` produce good output on my system. If you're still having an issue, I would say it is down to:

- Your version of `pod2text`.
- Your environment. Are you on a Linux or Windows machine (like I have to ask someone who's user name is *linuxrules49*. If you're piping this through `less` or `more`, what is your `$TERM` environment variable set to? It could be that your terminal is losing lines as it gets piped to either `more` or `less`.

Also, what editor are you using where it puts unwanted indents in your POD?

Comment: I did notice some `warning [p 3, 8.0i]: can't break line` comments when generating `perldoc` or `pod2man` and piping it through `nroff`. I traced this down to the generated manpage document and the extra long URLs. These URLS are 90+ characters long, and nroff couldn't break the line into under 60 characters. That's normal.

Comment: My OS is Opensuse Linux 2.6.37.6-0.7-default i686 i686 i386, GNU/Linux

Comment: also this is embeded in perlscript

Comment: This bug seems to stem from Tk::Text, I tried pod2html in the console, and it seems ok, but in Tk it is missing text

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it's trying to verify your `mailto` links, which definitively are not valid. If you want to use `mailto` links, make sure they contain something that at least looks like a valid email address.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the "can't break line" warning noted in David W's answer, that pod2usage annoyance can be avoided by doing the following:

1. Put the URL (or other offending long string) on its own line with whitespace at the beginning of the line.
2. Put a blank line before the line containing the URL.

Voila!

Btw, I would have left this as a comment in the answer rather than starting a whole new answer, but I apparently have [insufficient rep points](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work) :(